# Is it possible to modify how to exit fullscreen video on a web browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen, exit, chrome-remote-desktop

I have a video element that can go fullscreen. Once in Fullscreen mode, I want to disable exiting fullscreen when pressing ESC. Now, I know it's technically not possible since there is no ESC keydown events dispatched in fullscreen mode BUT Chrome Remote Desktop has something that's really interesting.

Instead of `Press ESC to exit fullscreen`, they show `Press and Hold ESC to exit fullscreen`.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved? The goal is to NOT exit fullscreen on ESC keydown but exit when holding ESC.

I know Google most likely modified the behaviour of the browser for Chrome Remote Desktop but it would be cool if we could do that as well :)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Turns out it is a niche feature called [Keyboard Lock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard/lock), only available in [Chrome (and Edge)](https://caniuse.com/?search=keyboard%20lock). If you lock the "Escape" key, Chrome understands that it needs to use "Hold Escape to Exit" instead of "Press Escape to Exit".

```js
navigator.keyboard.lock(["Escape"]);
```

Unofficial draft describing this exact behaviour
https://wicg.github.io/keyboard-lock/#escape-key